# Rails4: How to pass dynamic array from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have a problem creating Vote which contains value of points that user decided to give for a candidate (Borda Count Method). Values are in number_fields and I want them to be saved in Vote objects.

In my case I am only able to get value from the last number_field and I have no idea how to fix it. Other values are being overwritten so I came up with idea to create an array of points which contains values taken from many number_field_tag and pass them from view to controller.

Something about survey structure:
There is a Surv (survey) which contains many Polls (questions).
One Poll contains many Vote Options.
There are also Votes which save votes of user.

OUTPUT from params

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "poll"=>{"id"=>"11"}, "9"=>"17", "arr"=>"1212", "pnts"=>"", "10"=>"20", "11"=>"22", "commit"=>"Zagłosuj", "controller"=>"votes", "action"=>"create"}
```

VIEW:

show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h2>Twoja ankieta:</h2>

<h1>
  <%= @surv.topic %>
</h1>
<h2>
  <%= election_type %>
</h2>

<%= render 'voting_form' %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_surv_path(@surv) %> |
```

_voting_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag votes_path, method: :post, remote: true, id: 'voting_form' do %>

<% if @surv.votingtype == "default" %> 
  <%# here is unnecessary code ... %>
<% elsif @surv.votingtype == "bordy" %>  <%# BORDY %>
  <% @polls.each do |poll| %>
    <h2><%= poll.topic %></h2>
    <h2>POLL ID: <%= poll.id %></h2>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'poll[id]', poll.id %>


  <%= arr = [] %>
  <%= i = 0 %>
    <% poll.vote_options.each do |option| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= content_tag(:label) do %>

          <div class="select">
            <%= option.title %>

            <%= radio_button_tag option.poll_id, option.id %> 
                <%# if selected then vote is created %>

            <%= number_field_tag :point %>
            <%#= arr << :point %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag 'pnts', arr %>
                <%# some tries to pass params %>

          </div>

          <% end %>
        <%= visualize_votes_for option %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

    <p><b>Głosów razem: <%= poll.votes_summary %></b></p>
  <% end %>

  <% if current_user && current_user.voted_for3?(@surv) %>
    <p>Twój głos został DO ANKIETY został zapisany.</p>
  <% else %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Zagłosuj', class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>


<% end %>
```

CONTROLLER:

votes_controller.rb

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
def create
    @poll = Poll.find_by_id(params[:poll][:id])
    @surv = Surv.find_by_id(@poll.surv_id)

    puts "Surv id:"
    puts @surv.id

    @surv.polls.each do |p|
      puts "Poll ID (poll voted)."
      puts p.id

      puts "Vote option ID (vote option voted)"
      puts params[p.id.to_s]

      @option = p.vote_options.find_by_id(params[p.id.to_s])
      if p && !current_user.voted_for?(p)
        #here i would like to grab params specially specified for each poll
        @vote = @option.votes.create({user_id: current_user.id, points: params[:pnts]})
        #@vote = @option.votes.create({user_id: current_user.id, points: params[:point]})
        puts 'POINTS'
        puts params.inspect
      else
        render js: 'alert(\'Glosowales juz w tej ankiecie!\');'
        return
      end

      # end
    end

    @surv.update_attribute(:actual_votes, @surv.actual_votes+1)
     if (@surv.maximum_votes > 0 && @surv.actual_votes >= @surv.maximum_votes)
       respond_to do |format|
         format.html { redirect_to terminate_surv_path(@surv), notice: 'Ostatni głos został oddany' }
         format.js {render inline: "location.reload();" }
       end
    end

end

def vote_params
  params.require(:vote).permit(:points)
end

end
```

MODEL:

vote_option.rb

```
class VoteOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :surv
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :surv

  belongs_to :poll
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :poll

  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :votes

  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

vote.rb

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :vote_option
end

def surv_params
  params.require(:surv).permit(:topic, :votingtype,
    polls_attributes: [:id, :topic, :endtime, :endontime, :_destroy,
    vote_options_attributes: [:id, :title, :_destroy]
    ])
end
```

Please let me know if you need some additional code or informations to help me fix my problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: You would use [`accepts_nested_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html). Start by reading the rails api docs (linked). There are plenty of tutorials on the subject as well as questions on SO however a full example is way too long for a stackoverflow answer.